# Displaying the time from UTC timestamps for the users relative timezone

Tags: javascript, python, datetime, momentjs

I have some database entries that store the timestamp of the time it was entered in UTC

```py
# Python
"timestamp": datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

How do I find the users hour offset to adjust the time for them? for example, I know im 11 hours ahead so I add 11 hours to the timestamp, which im currently doing in JS.

I am using Moment.js to display relative times - see https://momentjs.com/

> Uploaded 'an hour ago'

In my front end JS I have a function that dynamically returns a formatted time based on the database UTC timestamp

```
// JavaScript
// eg. timestamp = 2019-09-20 23:10:18.117246+00:00
return moment(timestamp, "YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss").add(11, 'hours').startOf('hour').fromNow();
```

Do I figure out the 11 hours on the front end, or do I do it in the backend in Python and pass it through to the front end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the offset, I used the client side to figure that out so long as it's set correctly in their browser:

```
this.timeZoneOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

// -10 (Australia)
```

I then factored that in to my function to either subtract or add 10 hours.

*Note: If it's negative, it means it actually need to be positive, so in my case I would +10 hours to the UTC timestamp. If you want more precision, don't divide by 60. You will have the offset in minutes instead.*